# VirtoCommerce Azure Email Provider

Tags: azure, e-commerce, sendgrid, virtocommerce

I have deployed VirtoCommerce to the azure cloud service and the website is pretty functional aside from a few quirks. One of these quirks is that, after completing the checkout process no email gets sent to the user account.
The email account does exist and I have full access.
Do i need to set up something like [SendGrid](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email/)?
Or does it natively support that and how do i activate it?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get VirtoCommerce sending emails you will need to set up and account with SendGrid as mentioned in [their documentation](http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc1devguide/Email+Notifications).

You can get setup with SendGrid for free on Azure, [via this sign up form](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/sendgrid/sendgrid-azure/).

Once you have your account details, you can add them to VirtoCommerce by following the instructions for [configuring mailSettings (see 'Quick Overview')](http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc1devguide/Email+Notifications) in the Virto docs.